# How to fix: Number of occurrences of a letter in a string

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of letters that are in string. The code that I have written technically does what I want, but not the way I want to do it. For example, if I input "Hello World", I want my code to return "a=0 b=0 c=0 d=0 e=1 etc...." with the code I have written it returns "H=1, e=1, l=2 etc...."

Also how would I make sure that it is not case sensitive and it doesn't count spaces.

Code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Sequence {
    private static Scanner scan = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = null;
        System.out.print("Type text: ");
        str = scan.nextLine();

        int[] count = new int[255];

        int length = str.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
                count[str.charAt(i)]++;
            }

            char[] ch = new char[str.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
                ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
                int find = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
                {
                    if (str.charAt(i) == ch[j])
                find++;
                }

                if (find == 1) 
                {
                    System.out.print(str.charAt(i) + "=" + count[str.charAt(i)] + " ");
                }
            }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Well `int[] count = new int[255];` seems excessive. There are only 26 letters in the alphabet.

Comment: I set it to 255 so a user could input a longer string, that line doesn't involved the letters of the alphabet

Comment: I would recommend you work on naming your variables in a more descriptive fashion. It can surely be nice and clean looking when variables have short names, but don't sacrifice readability.

Comment: Do you need to consider case? For example if your input is _Hi there._, do you count two letter _H_ or one _H_ and one _h_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I hinted [in my original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862463/how-to-fix-number-of-occurrences-of-a-letter-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment102150811_57862463) you only need an array of 26 `int`(s) because there are only 26 letters in the alphabet. Before I share the code, it is important to note that Java `char` is an integral type (and, for example, 'a' + 1 == 'b'). That property is important, because it allows you to determine the correct offset in an array (especially if you force the input to lower case). Something like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Type text: ");
String str = scan.nextLine();
int[] count = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)); // not case sensitive
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // don't count "spaces" (or anything non-letter)
        count[ch - 'a']++; // as 'a' + 1 == 'b', so 'b' - 'a' == 1
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    if (count[i] != 0) {
        System.out.printf("%c=%d ", 'a' + i, count[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

If you really want to see all of the letters that have counts of zero (seems pointless to me), change

```
if (count[i] != 0) {
    System.out.printf("%c=%d ", 'a' + i, count[i]);
}
```

to remove the `if` and just

```
System.out.printf("%c=%d ", 'a' + i, count[i]);
```

Comment: Sorry I read your response incorrectly but the array of 26 makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `str = scan.nextLine();` to `str = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+","");`

`.toLowerCase()` is a method which makes every char in the string lowercase.

`.replaceAll()` is a method which replaces one char with another. In this case, it replaces whitespaces with nothing.